# How I can access into a Object in a view nested form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, nested, fields-for

I have this :

```
<% f.fields_for :permits do |permit| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= permit.access.name%></td>
        <td><center><%= permit.check_box :create %></center></td>
        <td><center><%= permit.check_box :edit %></center></td>
        <td><center><%= permit.check_box :_destroy %></center></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Where @Group `has_many :permits`    and permit `has_one :access` , all classes have `attr_accessor`.

Then I tried to print the name of access (`<%= permit.access.name%>`), but i get this error:

```
undefined method `access' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x3e3cce8>
```

How I can get the object var's into fields_for ?

from already thank you very much

Comment: Have you defined belongs_to :access in permit model and also have access_id as foriegn_key in permit table

Comment: You should not use models which are ending with an s (news, access).. Better you use something which can be differenciated (e.g. access_right / access_rights)

Comment: 1.- yes. the foreign keys is in orden.                                   2.- Thanks for the advice, I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `using permit.object.access.name`. `permit` is the form object.  `permit.object` is the instance of your Permit model.